# Trouble Active Directory windows 2012

Tags: windows, active-directory

We are using a windows server 2012 and we have a problem. Our stations use windows 7 and windows 8.

When we add a person in an access group in our Active directory, the user must restart their session in order to gain access.

By contrast, if I give access to a folder to a specific person, access is provided immediately without restarting the session.

Comment: This needs rewriting as it makes very little sense. Do not use abbreviations, consider using paragraphs and be more descriptive about your problem.

Comment: Execute `gpupdate /force` on Windows client and in some cases its not needed to reboot to get SOME of the new permisions. But if you want to make sure if the user have all the new permision you need to logg off

Comment: @nada Group Policies and NTFS permissions are not really related. This is a classic case of a user needing to get a new security token when their group membership is changed.

Answer (score 6):

Group membership is ascertained by the client at logon, hence the requirement for logging off and on again.

You must log off and on to refresh group membership, if adding a user directly to a folder for permissions then when they browse to the share the client reads permissions and matches their GUID against the permissions you have set, their group membership and/or guid have no need to change to do this.

If you add them to a group on active directory then when the client browses the share they will read the group, but they will not be aware that they are a member of that group until you log off and log on again.

There are hacks to work around this but they are far less pretty than getting a user to log on and off.

Comment: Is it possible to circumvent this rule. That causes a lot of problem unfortunately.

Comment: It's by design, it's not a particularly configurable feature of windows. Please explain the exact use case and how it causes issues, I will try to provide you a solution via one route or another.

Comment: Each group is connected to a specific folder on my network. I would like to add a used in a group and it does not need to restart the session for the access function.

Comment: This fact has always been true about Windows network security. You should not try to defeat this system. When a user logs on, they get a security token, which is like a keyring with a key for each resource they have access to. In order for new group membership to take effect, they must get a new security token before they can access resources allowed to the new group. The only supported way to get a new security token is to log off and back on again.

Comment: Maxime, by use case I need specifics. For instance, how many groups do you have, have you let your users dictate a culture in which they regularly request access to folders on a daily basis? Are your management team too paranoid and require each user request access to each project? There is a lot you can do to lighten the burden.